# CSS Bootstrap Table

Tags: html, css

How to restrict width to each column of bootstrap table?
I tried to play around but I cant seem to shrink the column.

https://plnkr.co/edit/XhwIUynVgAxMBpJo8x8N?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Table</h2>
      <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th style="width:20px">Firstname</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Anna</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Debbie</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>John</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just set your table to `width: auto` or give it a fixed width of your preference, e.g `width: 200px`

Comment: the thing is i want to append column so i dont want to limit the table size : ( I am doing angularJS with ng-repeat to append the column based on the number of entry in database. So I want each column to be fixed  size

Comment: You really want to add `columns`? Not `rows`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `table-layout: fixed` and have a static width of your columns.

```
.table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}

td, th {
  width: 90px;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/cn05610g/)

```css
.table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}

td, th {
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Anna</td>
            <td>Lastname</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Debbie</td>
            <td>Lastname</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Lastname</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the < colgroup> tag to format each column of your table

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cn05610g/3/)

```
<table class="table">
  <colgroup>
    <col style = "width : 50px">
    <col style = "width : 300px">
    <col style = "width : 100px">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Anna</td>
      <td>Lastname</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Debbie</td>
      <td>Lastname</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Lastname</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Don't forget to align your columns in your CSS

```
td, th { 

  text-align: left;
}
```